# Webpack + Babel error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to configure webpack and had everything up and running, but am now getting this same error. I've combed through a few other posts that seem to have been resolved by correcting spelling/grammar errors, but I can't seem to pinpoint anything wrong in my code. Is there something more serious happening?

```
ERROR in ./src/components/App/App.js
Module parse failed: /Users/Desktop/fred/src/components/App/App.js Unexpected token (7:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
|   render() {
|         return (
|           <h1>Hello</h1>;
|         );
|     };
| 
@ ./src/index.js 3:0-39
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/index
```

Here is my webpack.config:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var precss = require('precss');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/build/',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.png', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        context: __dirname,
        postcss: [
          autoprefixer
        ]
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
      }
    ],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import s from './App.scss';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello</h1>;
    );
  };

}

export default App;
```

my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App/App';

let element = React.createElement(App, {});
render(element, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fred test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a fred test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "fred",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "postcss": "^5.2.17",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "normalize.css": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `<Hello>` being defined?

Comment: That was actually not referencing anything. Have adjusted the code accordingly, but the error persists.

Comment: Wrap your h1 in a <div> and remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you defined both `module.rules` and `module.loaders`. Webpack completely ignores `module.loaders` (which only exists for compatibility reasons) whenever `module.rules` is present. In your case, all JavaScript rules are inside `module.loaders`, so none of them are being used.

To fix it put everything inside `module.rules`. And you also have two rules for `.js` files, as `/\.js?$/` matches `.j` and `.js`, because `?` means one or zero occurrences, similarly `/\.jsx?$/` matches `.js` and `.jsx`, which is what you really want, and it doesn't make sense to have a rule for `.j`.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Amazing - thanks so much. I hadn't appreciated there was a difference between the two. Everything seems back on track.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ES6 version of Javascript. You need preset config in webpack to understand and transpile that.

Can you try adding following to your webpack module config?

```
 loaders : [
      {
        test:/\.jsx?$/,
        exclude:/node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query:{
          presets: ['es2015','react','stage-0']
        }
      },
      // ... 
   ]
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried this and it didn't seem to work - also, are these presets not reflected in the .babelrc file?